# MAUI - Android Camera2 - How set Rotate and Crop in CaptureRequest

Tags: android, maui, android-camera2

I am trying to set the crop rect and the rotation for a capture request of the Android.Camera2.CameraDevice.
The CaptureRequest.Builder has a Set function where I can set the values for multiple keys.

But when I try to do something like:

```
builder.Set(CaptureRequest.ScalerRotateAndCrop180, null);
```

I get the message that this way is obsolete and that I should use the `ScalerRotateAndCropType` directly.

I can also do something like

```
builder.Set(CaptureRequest.ScalerRotateAndCrop, null);
```

This seems to be ok, but the rotation is missing.

So how do I use these functions correctly?

Comment: The method you use is right. You can check this document about the [CaptureRequest.ScalerRotateAndCrop Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.hardware.camera2.capturerequest.scalerrotateandcrop?view=net-android-34.0).